# can read only admin (semi-admin) be created on redmine project?

Tags: admin, redmine

I want to create a semi-admin in my redmine project with read-only permission. This semi-admin cannot edit, update any of the project issues, but can view all the projects and its issues. Can this be done in redmine 1.4.x ?

Comment: No, this is not possible without adding the user with an explicit role to all the projects.